# Nginx Static files for Flask Admin Page

Tags: nginx, flask

I have trouble serving the static files for flask admin page.

`admin = Admin(app, name='APPName', template_mode='bootstrap3')` 
`app.config['FLASK_ADMIN_SWATCH'] = 'Slate'`

Everything seems to be working on localhost but when I upload the application to the server(ubuntu) the bootstrap template no longer works.
The route to the static files for the Flask admin is
http://127.0.0.1:5000/admin/static/bootstrap/bootstrap3/swatch/Slate/bootstrap.min.css?v=3.3.5 on  localhost.
On the server its https://domainname.com/admin/static/bootstrap/bootstrap3/swatch/Slate/bootstrap.min.css?v=3.3.5 but its returning error 404.
Can anyone can point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I know this probably comes late, but here:

### Solution

Change your second line:

```py
admin = Admin(app, name='APPName', template_mode='bootstrap3') 
app.config['FLASK_ADMIN_SWATCH'] = 'slate'  # This line: 'Slate' to 'slate'
```

### Context

I was having the same issue you did. In my case, my config file contained this:

```py
# Flask Config
FLASK_ADMIN_SWATCH: str = "Superhero"
```

Worked locally, but not when deployed to an EC2 machine running CentOS, I got a 404.

I was running Windows locally and a Linux-based remote machine. I bet you are as well. Windows is case-insensitive, while Linux is case-sensitive.

Having the `FLASK_ADMIN_SWATCH` variable set to `Slate` means the path that arrives at flask is something similar to `admin/static/bootstrap/bootstrap4/Slate/bootstrap.min.css?v=4.2.1`. This doesn't present an issue for Windows, but it does for Linux.

Swatch themes reside inside `flask_admin/static/bootstrap/bootstrapX/swatch/`, each of them on a folder of their own, and all of them lowercase (e.g.: `cerulean`, `cosmo`, etc.). Your specific theme directory is `flask_admin/static/bootstrap/bootstrapX/swatch/slate/`.

Windows will try parsing `bootstrap/bootstrap4/Slate/bootstrap.min.css?v=4.2.1` and succeed at it, because it doesn't care for the case-ness of `Slate`, but Linux does, that's why it fails and ends up returning a 404.

```
# These paths are equivalent for Windows, but not for Linux.
bootstrap/bootstrap4/Slate/bootstrap.min.css?v=4.2.1
bootstrap/bootstrap4/slate/bootstrap.min.css?v=4.2.1
```